# error TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular

**Angular**
I am trying to perform two way binding using [(ngModel)] but it showing error.
I Have posted all the related files, also have tried using all the related queries but error is still there .. Can anyone help. I have also given the error which I am getting

---

***registers.component.html***

```
<div>
    <h3 class = "text-center">{{message}}</h3>
</div>
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <h4 class="mt-4 mb-4">Registration Form</h4>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label for = "username">Username</label>
                        <input type = "text" name = "username" [(ngModel)] = "user.username" id="username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your username" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label for = "firstname">FirstName</label>
                        <input type = "text" name = "firstname" [(ngModel)] = "user.firstname" id="firstname" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your firstname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label for = "lastname">Lastname</label>
                        <input type = "text" name = "lastname" [(ngModel)] = "user.lastname" id = "lastname" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your lastname" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label for = "age">Age</label>
                        <input type = "text" name = "age" [(ngModel)] = "user.age" id="age" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your age" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label for = "password">Password</label>
                        <input type = "text" name = "password" [(ngModel)] = "user.password" id="password" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your password" />
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <input class = "btn btn-success" type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Register" (click) = "registerNow()" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { AllUsersComponent } from './all-users/all-users.component';
import { RegistersComponent } from './registers/registers.component';
import { CodeComponent } from './code/code.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    AllUsersComponent,
    RegistersComponent,
    CodeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***registers.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserServiceService } from '../user-service.service';
import { User } from '../user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registers',
  templateUrl: './registers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registers.component.scss']
})
export class RegistersComponent implements OnInit {
  
  user : User = new User("","","",0,"");
  message : any;
  constructor(private service : UserServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public registerNow(){
    let response = this.service.doRegistration(this.user);
    response.subscribe(data => {
      this.message = data;
    });
  }

}
```

***User.ts***

```
export class User{
    constructor(
        username : string,
        firstname : string,
        lastname : string,
        age : number,
        password : string
    ){}
}
```

***error which I am getting ***

```
Build at: 2021-09-01T07:03:25.440Z - Hash: d61cbae04ddda1edb5f9 - Time: 552ms

Error: src/app/registers/registers.component.html:12:84 - error TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'User'.

12                         <input type = "text" name = "username" [(ngModel)] = "user.username" id="username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your username" />      
                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/registers/registers.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './registers.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component RegistersComponent.


Error: src/app/registers/registers.component.html:12:84 - error TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'User'.

12                         <input type = "text" name = "username" [(ngModel)] = "user.username" id="username" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Enter your username" />      
                                                                                      ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/registers/registers.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './registers.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: export type User  {
        username : string,
        firstname : string,
        lastname : string,
        age : number,
        password : string
}

and instead of instantiating a new Class .. pass default values in HTML 
[(ngModel)] = "user.username || '0'"

to give type of an Object in Typescript don't uses classes, use type or interface

Answer (score 5):

You need declare your user like:

```
export class User{
 public username : string,
 public firstname : string,
 public lastname : string,
 public age : number,
 public password : string

  constructor(
      username : string,
      firstname : string,
      lastname : string,
      age : number,
      password : string
  ){
      this.username=username
      this.firstname=firstname
      this.lastname=lastname
      this.age=age
      this.password=password
   }
}
```

You can use also an abreviate way (see the "public" in the constructor)

```
export class User{
  constructor(
      public username : string,
      public firstname : string,
      public lastname : string,
      public age : number,
      public password : string
  ){}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your User class, you will need to define the constructor parameters as public, this is a shorthand way of declaring the fields as properties of your class and assigning them the values during the constructor call

Comment: Hi,  applied those changes ..it worked thanks.